# Working with angles in complex number fields

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, angle

I am trying to convert the following complex number into polar coordinates: $$A = -3 + i4.$$

I got $A = 5e^{-i53.13},$ by plugging in $\arctan\frac4{-3}= -53.13º.$ But the given solution uses $126.76º$ instead. I notice that the given angle is obtained via 180º - 53.13º, but I do not understand why this is the case?

This is not a check-my-work question; rather, I want to understand how $126.76º$ is equivalent to $-53.13º.$ If an angle is negative, it means that we are going clockwise with respect to the real axis; thus, to get the angle in the counterclockwise direction, shouldn't it be $360º - 53.13º ?$

Comment: Please use radians for angles

Comment: AFAIK, they are not "equivalent". My computer (julia) gives me: $atan(4,-3)/pi*180\approx 126.87$. Your number is in the second quadrant, so its angle should be in $[90,180]$

Comment: "*I did A=5e−i53.13. I know my conversion is correct,...*". Your conversion is not correct. I suppose you calculated $3 + i\cdot4$ abd neglected the negative sign before $3$.

Comment: Important note: $\pi$ radians is the same as $180$ degrees. But $e^{i\pi}=-1$, while $e^{i180}$ is something else entirely

Comment: My calculator is in degrees, if i plug in arctan(4/-3) = -53.13º, I have plugged it in multiple times and still get that angle, where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have corrected the question as to not assume the angle calculation is correct.

Comment: I just read online that for complex numbers, when the real component is less than zero, then the conversion becomes: In degrees arctan(4/-3) + 180º. Why is that the case, does this apply for a real-only plane as well?

Comment: arctan$(4/-3)$ is solved on a calculator by presuming that the cosine is positive and that therefore, the angle is between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ (i.e. $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ)$.  Such a presumption by the calculator violates the constraints of the problem, which requires that the cosine be negative and the sine be positive.  That is, in the given problem : $(-3 + i4)$ has a negative Real component and a positive Imaginary component.  In effect, you (inadvertently, via your calculator) attacked $(3 + i[-4])$.

Comment: Amazing explanation, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Observe that $$\tan (120º)=\tan (-60º)=-\sqrt3,$$ and$$\arctan(-\sqrt3)=-60º\ne120º.$$
2. The point is that $\arctan$ has **range** $(-90º,90º),$ and that $$\large\tan\theta=s\;\iff \;\text{for some integer } k,\;\theta=\arctan(s)+180ºk.$$
3. Since $\arctan\left(\frac4{-3}\right)= -53.13º$ and $\,A=−3+4i\,$ lies in the second quadrant, $A$'s polar angle $\theta$ can be found using the above identity with $k=1.$

   So, $\theta=126.76º,$ which matches the answer given to you.
4. Note that $$\large A\ne5e^{i126.76}\\\large A\ne5e^{i126.76º}\\\large A\ne5e^{i2.21\text{rad}}\\\large A=5e^{i2.21}.$$